# How can I rephrase a question with if clause, to be answered only if the event of the "if" clause happened

Tags: past-tense, conditionals

I would like to ask a question which is to be answered only if some past condition is met:

*If you did something in the past, could you tell me more about it?*

How should I rephrase it?

Comment: Sounds like the context is something like a job interview or applicant questionnaire. If that is indeed the case, I believe the usual approach is to ask two questions: Did you do X in the past? (Yes/No) If yes, what were the circumstances?

Comment: It's not an interview with questions. It's an email inviting people to answer some questions: "if you did something in the past, I would like you to answer some questions..."

Comment: Please reply is you have any experience with X.

Comment: @iohanson, I rephrased your question in the hope it would be clearer. Please correct it if I've changed the intent at all.

Comment: Why exactly are you concerned? I don't see much danger of people telling you about something they did in the past if in fact they never did anything. But on the other hand, it's a racing certainty that *everybody* has done *something* in the past, even if it was only *breathing*.

Comment: The question could be posed in the present perfect tense e.g. (i) "**If you have already used/purchased/travelled** [name of company] to book a hotel/our product/with us (etc.), please complete the following questionnaire."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you did something in the past, could you tell me more about it?* (i.e. If X then explain Y) could be rephrased in several ways - some of which will depend on the actual question & context.

Some examples:

Could you elaborate on prior experiences with using this feedback form?

If you have ordered from us before, please let us know how satisfied you were with our service. - *ask for specific details re. Y*

What was your impression during past visits to this city? - *implicit 'if you visited the city earlier'*

Were you a target of 419 scams purportedly from here? Can you answer a few questions to help us identify any security issues? - *The 2nd question is basically a 'then' clause, **if** the first one applies.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever X, and if so, what was your experience?

Comment: I may have misunderstood OP's request, but this seems to me to be the exact opposite of what he wants. Your version invites even people who *haven't* "X'ed" to reply, simply in order to say they never did it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you require that the request be phrased as a question?

> Please tell me about your experience with *X*, ***if any***.

or

> Please tell me about ***any experience you have had*** with *X*.

Comment: I admit that these are similar to Alok’s answers, except I reversed the order (leading with the request for information).